# php only allow letters but doesnt work on @, - etc

Tags: php, string, email, key, preg-match

I've added a form to my website to subscribe to my newsletter.
The problem is, I use the `first_name` tag for email address but it doesn't allow @ or #.

```
$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required 
$email_address = $_POST['email_address']; // required     

$error_message = ""; 
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) { 
      $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />'; 
}
```

Also I want the `email address` allow to use keys as @ or #.

Comment: _"The problem is, I use the 'first_name' tag for email address"_ What? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: You need to edit the regular expressions which you check against and add  the characters you want to be allowed, for example
`$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-@#]+$/";` and
`$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-@#]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-@#]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';`

Comment: To validate an email address use `filter_var` with the option `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex for first_name is

```
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
```

Which restricts you to only latin characters, space, period, single quote and dash.

If you wanted to allow `@` and `#` then you should add these as extra characters to the allowable character list:

```
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'@#-]+$/";
```

Important: you must to add these before the last `-` or the `-` will be interpreted as specifying a character range.

A better question though is why are you restricting the user's name at all? If someone has a non-ANSI character in their name (eg russian, chinese, japanese, korean or even accented latin characters) then you will prevent them from signing up. A user's name should really have no restrictions at all, and if you have issues with other characters then there is a bug in the code that generates any emails.

Repeat this for the email allowable character lists (remembering to put them before any `-` at the end)

A final comment: Your regex for email addresses has much bigger problems than these characters. Most obviously it will prevent legitimate GTLDs that are longer than 4 characters at the end from working (eg `.museum`), or the `+` symbol before the `@` (very useful with gmail addresses).

A fully compliant regular expression for parsing email addresses is *extremely* complicated (see http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html). I generally use the regex specified in the HTML5 spec (https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#valid-e-mail-address) since this will be the one the browser also uses for `<input type="email">` but there are many alternatives (see [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address))

Email regex in html5 spec:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/
```

Comment: As first thanks for your comment, i changed the code i had before into your code and published it to my website. Then when i enter an email address in the first name it runs the error code and wont send it to my email.